# Use user certificates inside webview fails

Tags: android, webview, certificate, android-webview

I'm trying to embed a webview which embed an url which use a personal certificate to authenticate in the web. If I use a normal Chrome, when I reach this point, a system dialog appears to select the certificate but when I tried on the webview, when I reach this point of the system dialog, the web fails with message that cannot access.

Is it possible to do that? This is my code for the webview.

```
val myWebView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.wv)
        myWebView.loadUrl(url)
        myWebView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
                view: WebView?,
                request: WebResourceRequest?
            ): Boolean {
                return false
            }
        }

        myWebView.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient () {
            override fun onJsAlert(
                view: WebView?,
                url: String?,
                message: String?,
                result: JsResult?
            ): Boolean {
                return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result)
            }

            override fun onJsConfirm(
                view: WebView?,
                url: String?,
                message: String?,
                result: JsResult?
            ): Boolean {
                return super.onJsConfirm(view, url, message, result)
            }

            override fun onJsPrompt(
                view: WebView?,
                url: String?,
                message: String?,
                defaultValue: String?,
                result: JsPromptResult?
            ): Boolean {
                return super.onJsPrompt(view, url, message, defaultValue, result)
            }
        }

        myWebView.settings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
        myWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        myWebView.settings.loadsImagesAutomatically = true
        myWebView.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
        myWebView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        myWebView.settings.builtInZoomControls = true
        myWebView.settings.allowContentAccess = true
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Webview is likely using the network security policy of your app, while Chrome is using the system's policy. If this is the case, you can embed your custom cert in the app and add a `network_security_config.xml` that defines it as trusted. See [here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config) for details.

Comment: Thank you. But Is there a way to implement a chrome embed webview like the real browser, to have the same behaibour?

Comment: According to [this article|https://httptoolkit.com/blog/android-11-trust-ca-certificates/], it's no longer possible on Android 11+. The user will need to add it manually through the Settings app or you will need to embed the certificate in the app and trust it in your network_security_config.xml